# Langlands conjectures in higher dimensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures, ag.algebraic-geometry

Geometric class field theory (curves over a finite field) has been generalized
to higher dimensional varieties over a finite field (and other arithmetical fields). Some of the key names here are Lang, Serre, Bloch, Kato-Saito...

Question: Does there exist a precise formulation of Langlands's conjectures which constitutes a non-abelian generalization of these results?

Probably relevant: Kazhdan's talk [here](http://www.math.harvard.edu/conferences/gross_10/panel/panel.pdf) at the Panel on Open Questions held at Gross's 60th Birthday Conference.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no formulation of geometric Langlands for higher dimensional varieties. However, there is a lot of interesting things in this direction discussed here: 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6457/kapranovs-analogies

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other MO question. Ben-Zvi's answer seems to suggest that generalizations of the geometric version seem to be limited by physics (I may be misreading his answer -- I apologize).

I am wondering about a generalization of the old-fashioned classical (arithmetical) Langlands's conjectures.

Answer (score 6):

From what I remember, Kapranov's paper "Analogies between the Langlands correspondence and topological quantum field theory" has some speculations about this. A wise old friend once called it the most speculative paper he'd ever seen in print.

Comment: Thanks! very interesting paper..but sadly it does not contain a precise formulation of the conjectural generalization.